# Python subprocess + scp - can't read all output

Tags: python, linux, ssh, scp

I'm trying to SCP a file between machines and I need to fail when the user hasn't set up a private/public certificate to do passwordless logins. Unfortunatly, using subprocess.Popen I can't figure out how to capture the following output:

```
The authenticity of host '***' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ***.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)
```

It always shows up on the console and I can't get it in my program to detect it.

Here's some example code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['scp', 'user@server:/location/file.txt', '/someplace/file.txt',
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
print 'result: %s' % repr(proc.stderr.readline())
```

I've tried many other permutations. This one still prompts me, and not Python to enter yes/no. At least when I type no though I get:

```
result: 'Host key verification failed.\r\n'
```

Comment: You may want to consider trying [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) which is a native Python SSH library. You'll have more control over the connections and won't have to deal with Popen.

Comment: @greg-hewgill I can't use a third party library in this case.

Comment: Can we see the code you are using?  You likely need to connect the the stderr pipe of your subprocess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'The authenticity of host '***' can't be established'` means the machine your connecting from hasn't been told to save the other ends (server) identity to the `known_hosts` file and it asking if you trust the machine.  You can change the ssh client to just add it automatically without prompting you.

try this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-o BatchMode=yes',
                                'user@server:/location/file.txt',
                                '/someplace/file.txt'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
print 'result: %s' % repr(proc.stderr.readline())
```

---

With the above code i get:

```
me@myMachine:~$ python tmp.py 
result: 'Host key verification failed.\r\n'
me@myMachine:~$
```

If I use disable `StrictHostKeyChecking` i get:

```
me@myMachine:~$ python tmp.py
result: 'Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).\r\n'
me@myMachine:~$ python tmp.py
```

So it looks like it is printing the first line from stderr with `BatchMode` turned on :)

Comment: That is helpful and something I tried to do earlier, but I'm more interested in knowing that the public/private certificate isn't setup and erroring on that condition. Is there a way to tell SSH either work without further interaction or fail?

Comment: @sudoer This looks like it will be a touch one. Watching scp on my (linux) machine, it looks like scp spawns its own subprocess (an ssh process) that opens its own filehandle to '/dev/tty'.  Unless there is a switch to scp, that will control this behavior in the ssh process it spawns, i think this method might not work for you. Can you check the exit status of the scp process to know if it worked?

Answer (score 3):

I've run into something similar before, though in my case it was actually helpful. I believe ssh and friends don't actually read stdin and print on stdout or stderr, they do funky things to hook up with the terminal you're running in directly.

I believe the reasoning is they they're supposed to be able to talk to the user directly, even when run through wrapper shell scripts, because the user knows the password, not the calling script (and probably they deliberately don't want calling scripts to have the opportunity to intercept a password).

[Edit to add]: According to the man page on my system, scp does have a flag that might do what you want:

> ```
>  -B      Selects batch mode (prevents asking for passwords or passphrases).
> ```

Comment: Interesting. As I commented els where - is there a way for me to tell ssh/scp to fail if it needs any further information from the user?

Comment: scp apparantly has a -B flag for "batch mode". I've edited my answer.